# Finding locations of a char in a string

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, indexof

How can I get the position of certain characters in a string?

Example: my string = "hello, what you doing"

and I would like to return the position of **o** from those string which should return me position numbers 4, 13 & 17. I've tried *str.IndexOf* but it only returns the first occurrence of **o**.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    Dim str = "hello, what you doing"
    Dim dIndex = str.IndexOf("o")
    If (dIndex > -1) Then
        Console.WriteLine(dIndex.toString())
    End If
```

any method will do.

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: IndexOf has an overload that allows you to pass the starting position. You can build a loop around this and get all the indexes you need

Comment: I don't get how u mean by that, actually this is my first time dealing with vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [overload of IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes the position to start looking from.

So once you have found the position of the first matching character, you can tell it to carry on looking starting just after that position.

Here I made a function which returns a list of the positions. (If there are no matches then the list will be empty.)

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

Module Module1

    Function IndexesOf(s As String, c As Char) As List(Of Integer)
        Dim positions As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim pos = s.IndexOf(c)
        While pos >= 0
            positions.Add(pos)
            pos = s.IndexOf(c, pos + 1)
        End While

        Return positions

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim os = IndexesOf("hello, what you doing", "o"c)
        For Each pos In os
            Console.WriteLine(pos)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Output:

> 4
>   13
>   17

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, you can call `IndexOf` in a loop and specify the `startIndex` as 1 more than the last detected index.  Here's an extension method you can use that does that internally:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StringExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Iterator Function IndexesOf(source As String, value As Char) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
        Dim startIndex As Integer
        Dim index = source.IndexOf(value)

        Do Until index = -1 OrElse startIndex = source.Length
            Yield index

            startIndex = index + 1
            index = source.IndexOf(value, startIndex)
        Loop
    End Function

End Module
```

You can call that in pretty much the same way you would `IndexOf` to get a list of all the indexes, e.g.

```
Dim str = "babbabbbabbbbab"

For Each index In str.IndexesOf("a"c)
    MessageBox.Show(index.ToString())
Next
```

Because the method is an iterator, you can stop that `For Each` loop part way through and the method will stop its `Do` loop at the same point.  If you want a full list that you can access any way you want, call `ToArray` or `ToList` on the result.  You can also do things like call `Take(3)` to get just the first three indexes, etc.

If you don't want the extension method, just use the loop from within it, replacing the `Yield` statement with some other action using the found index.

EDIT:

Here's a version of the method that would work in VS 2008, because it's not an iterator or extension method:

```
Public Function IndexesOf(source As String, value As Char) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim startIndex As Integer
    Dim index = source.IndexOf(value)
    Dim indexes As New List(Of Integer)

    Do Until index = -1 OrElse startIndex = source.Length
        indexes.Add(index)

        startIndex = index + 1
        index = source.IndexOf(value, startIndex)
    Loop

    Return indexes
End Function
```

Comment: I'm unable to create those module

Comment: @Tony The first part of [www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets9p7.html](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets9p7.html) shows how to create a module. Just name yours "StringExtensions" instead of "modVerify".

Comment: thanks @AndrewMorton, but I got an error on **Yield** says *declarations Expected*, is there's something to do with VS version? since I'm using VS2008

Comment: @Tony I recommend that you use a more modern version of VS if possible - the [community edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) is free.

Comment: I missed the reference to VS 2008 in the OP. Is there a particular reason that you're using a decade-old version of VS? If you have to then you have to but, given that VS 2017 Community has pretty much all the functionality of Pro and is free, it makes sense for most people to be using that.

Comment: I added a slightly different version of the method that will work for you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I couldn't answer to why I'm using VS2008, since this provided by my company that I'm working with. maybe its their own policy as a company or something.

Comment: how am I gonna call that new function, since I'm getting error of **Value of System.Collections.Generic.List(OfInteger) cannot be converted to Integer** and I've already imports the System.Collections

Comment: @jmcilhinney You didn't miss the reference to VS2008 in the OP - I added it as it seemed to be important information.

Answer (score 2):

A solution from the [System.TextRegularExpressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Text.RegularExpressions);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) assembly is missing.
It should be available in Visual Studio 2008, more or less as it is now.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim MyString As String = "hello, what you doing"
Dim pattern As String = "o"
```

[Regex.Matches()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Matches_System_String_System_String_) returns a collection of matching elements. A [Match class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) has some properties; among those, the `Index` property, which reports the position of a matched element.
The position of a `Char` inside a `String`, in this case.

```
Dim Indexes As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(MyString, pattern)

For Each Position As Match In Indexes
    Console.WriteLine(Position.Index)
Next
```

This is more or less the same. It directly generates an array of Integers containing the matched positions:
I'm not sure if this can work in VS 2008.

```
Dim Indexes As Integer() = Regex.Matches(MyString, pattern).OfType(Of Match)().
                           Select(Function(m) m.Index).ToArray()
```

---

As Andrew Morton suggested, a note about special character (can be referenced as `metacharacters`) used by the .Net Regex class for its operations. These symbols, mainly:
`\, *, +, ?, ^, $,., #, |, {, [, (,)` + space (`CharW(32)`).

See the referece pages about the .Net Regex literals, operators, and constructs:
[Regular Expression Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

What happens if you have a string like this:
(Just changed the `"o"` with a `"."`)

```
Dim MyString As String = "hell., what are y.u d.ing"
Dim pattern As String = "."
```

Since in Regular Expressions the `.` symbols is used as a wildcard, matching any character, the returned `Indexes` list will contain the positions of all the characters contained in the evaluated string.

If you know in advance that you have to include/search for a special character, you can insert an hardcoded escape:

```
Dim pattern As String = "\."
```

In this case, the `Indexes` list will contain 3 matched elements.

But, if you don't know beforehand the nature of the character representing your pattern, you can use the [Regex.Escape()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Escape_System_String_) method to escape the special character that might eventually appear.

```
Dim pattern As String = "."
pattern = Regex.Escape(pattern)
```

The `Indexes` list will contain 3 matched elements as before.

This method can be applied to more complex Patterns than the single character used here. See the `Regex.Escape()` documentation for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

With linq:

```
Dim indices = str.Select(Function(s, i) New With {s, i}) _
                 .Where(Function(x) x.s = "o"c) _
                 .Select(Function(x) x.i)
```