# Search first ocurrence of specific character in RichTextBox returns -1

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, richtextbox

I am just trying to find the position index of the first whitespace of the current line.

I have written a code that works good only for the first whitespace in the whole richtextbox, but if I try to get the index of the position of the following whitespaces (same line or in the following lines), I always get -1 and I don't know why.

I have been reading the following documentation:
[MSDN documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find?view=netframework-4.5#System_Windows_Forms_RichTextBox_Find_System_Char___System_Int32_)

And I have used the **Find(Char[], Int32)** option, in the following way:

```
RTB1.Find(CChar(" "), RTB1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine)
```

The problem is that I get -1 when I try to detect the following one whitespaces after the first. If I use that code to detect the first whitespace of the first line, I get a 6 as a result (and that is correct). But for the following whitespaces I always get -1, even if it's the first line or the following lines.

Comment: What is the position of the caret when you run this code?

Comment: [Finding locations of a char in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376515/finding-locations-of-a-char-in-a-string/51380035#51380035).

Comment: Why are you using `GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine`?  The current line is the one containing the caret, which is likely to be the last line.  If you want to find the next index after the one you just found then you need to use the index you just found as the starting point.

Comment: No, the accepted answer does not work good.  If you think it does then it's because you haven't tested it properly.  Try adding "a b c" to the first line, "d" to the second line and then put the caret at the end and you'll see that it returns -1, just like your original code.  Neither works properly and that becomes obvious with proper testing, which requires more than just one trial.

Comment: @jmcilhinney As you suggest, I am testing the behaviour of the codes more in deep. I have tried the test you have suggested: I have added "a b c" to the first line and "d" to the second line. In any caret position of the first line (including the last position of the first line) it returns 1 (that is correct). In the second line, before "d" it returns 1 (incorrect because there is not any empty space on the second line), after "d" it returns -1 (correct I think, because there is not any empty space). I have unchecked as correct the codex's answer.

Comment: @VisualVincent the position of the caret could be any within the RTB control. I have tried different ones to check that the code that codex suggested, works good unless you place the caret on the first index of the current line. In the first index the result is not correct.

Comment: Based on your question, the position of the caret is not relevant to what you want to do so the code you use to do it should have no dependence on the position of the caret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you the indexes of all space characters in one go:

```
Dim index = RichTextBox1.Find({" "c})

Do Until index = -1
    MessageBox.Show(index.ToString())

    index = RichTextBox1.Find({" "c}, index + 1)
Loop
```

If you wanted to get them one at a time then something like this is what you want:

```
Private index As Integer = -1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    index = RichTextBox1.Find({" "c}, index + 1)

    If index = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No more spaces")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(index.ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have use your code to solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Dim last = Me.rtb.Find(New Char() {" "}, Me.rtb.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine)
```

Comment: How is that any different than what the OP is already doing? Also, please note that code formatting is done by indenting each line of code by four spaces. The backticks ( \` ) are only used for `inline` code, for example if you in the middle of a sentence mention a `Button` or `RichTextBox.Find()`, etc. You can read more about this in the [Markdown and Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Perfect, it works really good. But, one question: Why my code just worked for the first whitespace and not for the following ones?

Comment: @RichardSteele, this code is basically no different to what you were using except that it will work with `Option Strict On`.  If you had a problem, you still have the same problem.  My guess is that, on this test, you just had the caret in a different place.

Comment: On second thoughts, it won't work with `Option Strict On` because it uses a `String` as an element in a `Char` array, so it doesn't have that either.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have tried the code that codex suggest and it works. Using my code, it returns -1 if I try to detect the following empty spaces after the first one (mine only works for the first one). Tried a couple of times and carefully placing the caret in different positions of the text. Using codex's code and placing the caret on the position 0, it returns the position index of the first empty space of the last line.

Comment: I have unchecked @codex answer as the correct answer because I have tried more in deep the codex's solution and it works better than mine, but it doesn't work 100% correclty. When I place the caret in the first index of the current line, the result is not correct. When I place the caret after the first index of the current line, the result is correct.